# Как отправить определенное сообщение из телеграм бота в телеграм канал

Tags: telegram-bot, telebot

```
import telebot

from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('Token')





user_dict = {}


class User:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.age = None
        self.sex = None


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_command(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=3)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton('Ассортимент')
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton('Информация')
    item3 = types.KeyboardButton('Оставить заявку на покупку')

    markup.add(item1, item2, item3)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет,{0.first_name}!'.format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types={'text'})
def bot_message(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'Оставить заявку на покупку':
            msg = bot.reply_to(message, 'Как вас зовут:')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_name_step)



def process_name_step(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    name = message.text
    user = User(name)
    user_dict[chat_id] = user
    msg = bot.reply_to(message, 'Какой товар вас интересует:')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_age_step)


def process_age_step(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    age = message.text
    user = user_dict[chat_id]
    user.age = age
    msg = bot.reply_to(message, 'Метро где вы проживаете:')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_sex_step)


def process_sex_step(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton('Принять✅')
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    sex = message.text
    user = user_dict[chat_id]
    user.sex = sex
    markup.add(item1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     'Ваша заявка скоро будет рассмотренна ''\n ___________________________''\n Ваше имя:' + user.name + '\n Товар:' + str(
                         user.age) + '\n Метро:' + user.sex, reply_markup=markup)







bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

**

Здаача заключается в чем,

1. Юзер отвечает на вопросы которые задает ему бот
2. Складывается целое сообщение
3. Отправляется в телеграм канал

Не получается решить проеблему с отправкой сообщения в тг канал(3 пункт), все что я пробовал
писать не работает, подскажите как можно это написать  **

Все это пишу в целях собственного развития

Comment: В чём конкретно проблема заключается? У канала есть ID, берите его и отправляйте

Comment: Надо сделать что бы от бота месседж пересылался, а я не пойму как, пробовал через bot.forward_message, не работает так (пример):
        if 'ваше имя' in text and 'какие товар' in text and 'на какой станции' in text:
            bot.forward_message(chat, message.chat.id, message.text)

Comment: http://i.prntscr.com/gkuCe8u6SVuHHeFP1ebmZA.png

Comment: ID канала Вам известен?

Comment: И условие у Вас какое-то странное, в сообщении от юзера должно быть "ваше имя" + "какие товар"  + "на какой станции" всё вместе.

Comment: id известен, он должен стоять вместо *chat*

Comment: Просто Ваш код отправки сообщения в условие не проходит. При каком конкретно случае должно пересылаться сообщение в канал?

Comment: Там через некст степ хендлер бот задает вопрос в итоге получается вот это http://i.prntscr.com/GZM5ms_xR_qiE67omCV8mA.png

Comment: http://i.prntscr.com/CZ1PnoR8SZOJAai1PcAK-A.png вот при этих условиях if....

Answer (score 1):

В message.text находится текст сообщения, которое отправил пользователь, а не бот.

Для пересылки сообщения есть метод [forwardMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#forwardmessage).

Если Вам известен ID канала, куда должно пересылаться сообщение, то просто делайте это в самом последнем хэндлере, когда пользователь заполнил все данные:

```py
...

def process_sex_step(message):
    ...

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     'Ваша заявка скоро будет рассмотренна ''\n ___________________________''\n Ваше имя:' + user.name + '\n Товар:' + str(
                         user.age) + '\n Метро:' + user.sex, reply_markup=markup)

    channel_id = -1234567890 # Здесь укажите ID Вашего канала
    bot.forward_message(chat_id=channel_id, from_chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.message_id)
```

Comment: Спасибо, но почему от отправляет только последнее сообещние? Скрин 1.http://i.prntscr.com/K6t-HR72RKue9jU9L1cVGQ.png Скрин 2.http://i.prntscr.com/7uiaDrmWR3GoXmZmpoAC3g.png

Comment: http://i.prntscr.com/mG4lYOnOQoaxkvg5AG09cQ.png Код, Пробовал еще так http://i.prntscr.com/iBEGQcyaRiChyxUt3ElN2g.png , рабочий вариант  только, но он отправляет только последнее сообещние я так понял http://i.prntscr.com/dYrxINfSROKXmDgxLMbBqw.png

Comment: Он пересылает сообщения от юезра, а надо что бы конечное от бота :(

Comment: Так тогда помимо отправки сообщения юзеру в чат, отправляйте его в канал, вместо `message.chat.id` используйте ID канала, в чём проблема?